# Error creating table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I  keep getting  errors  when   running this query in  phpmyadmin to create a  customers table for my database.

This is the query I am trying to use:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
cust_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name character(30),
phone character(15),
);
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be a redundant `,` here: `phone character(15),`

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a comma after `phone character(15)`

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
cust_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name character(30),
phone character(15)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to put a comma for last column.

Remove comma after phone character(15).

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
cust_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name character(30), 
phone character(15)
);
```