# Creating a table with primary and forgein key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

im trying to   create a products table with a primary and foreign key  with  this.[image: data]
...

here is the code  that i have tried so  far

```
    CREATE TABLE products
(
prod_id int NOT NULL,
prod_name int NOT NULL,
price varchar(15)
5on_hand varchar(15),
supp_id varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (prod_id),
FOREIGN KEY (supp_id)
);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have a question?  Is something not working about your code (such as the declaration of a foreign key with no `references` clause)?

Comment: Also, missing a `,` in 3rd line.

Comment: Your data type choice for `prod_name` and `price` is strange.

Comment: Here is another similar question asked by you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538823/error-creating-table-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is a reference to a field in another table. To specify a foreign key, you have to specify what field(s) it refers *to*. The database cannot guess this.

So, guessing that `supp_id` refers to the `id` in the `Suppliers` table, your foreign key clause should look like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (supp_id) REFERENCES Supplier(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage the following:

- All tables have an primary key column that is an integer and auto-incremented.
- Names should be character strings.
- Prices should be decimals.

So, I'm thinking something like this is appropriate:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductId int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Price decimal(19, 4),
    OnHand integer, -- assuming this is quantity on-hand
    SupplierId int,
    FOREIGN KEY (SupplierId) REFERENCES Suppliers(SupplierId)
);
```